# would these be compatible replacement solid state AC Relays?

Tags: electrical, relay

I am replacing a relay for an appliance (stove).

I cannot find a replacement relay, however I thought I'd confirm if the following relays would be compatible:

1)
input 90-250 VAC
output 24-440VAC
25 Amps

2)
input 80-250 VAC
output 24-380 VAC
25 Amps

The original relay is:

- input 90-250 VAC output 40-440 VAC 40 Amps

option 1) seems to fall within best reasonable range. only major difference is the 40 Amps vs 25 Amps. 
since 110 volt standard outlet produces max 20 Amps,I reckon should be sufficient.

any issues you see with this?

Thanks

Comment: A typical 110 volt standard outlet is 15 or 20 amps. But a stove (unless this is just the igniter/controls for a gas stove) is typically 30 - 50 amps.

Comment: thanks for response. each relay output going to heat element for oven. so that takes 30-50amps?

Comment: stove is plugged in to 120volt x 2 (each 40 amp).

Comment: I found one at: Input Resistance/Power:50-280VAC 
Output voltage: 2-480V AC
Output current: 40A